# How do I get all parsed data for each each business listing and keep it aligned in a CSV file?

Tags: python, html, csv, xpath

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 with Python 2.7.6 to parse a Yellowpages.com, YP, Apartments page. I am using lxml and xpath. YP pages appear to have the same layout. The center of each page lists each apartment. Each center apartment has an index nuber. There are 30 indexed apartments per page.  Other apartments are listed at the top, bottom and right side of the page and look to be advertisements and of no interest for parsing.
I parsed the page getting a count of each item listed for an apartment. If there are 30 numbered apartments I get different counts for the items and it appears something is wrong. For example:

```
lenIdxBusNames = 30
lenBusinessNames = 32
lenStreets = 30
lenPageHrefs = 15.
```

I wrote the items/elements to rows in a CSV. BusinessName and pageHref columns  are misaligned. BusinessName column is shifted up by one row.  There are only 15 pageHrefs which means some are missing.  Instead of being kept in the same row as the other items they are listed in the first 16 rows of that column. Some of the search paths are:

```
idxBusNames =         tree.xpath('//h3[@class="n"]/text()'), 
businessNames =       tree.xpath('//h3/a[@class="business-name"]/text()'), 
streets =             tree.xpath('//p[@class="adr"]/span[1]/text()') and 
pageHrefs =           tree.xpath('//a[@class="track-visit-website"]/@href')
```

I found xpaths using Firefox firebug.  More detail is in the attachment.

Thanks for your help,
Bob

Comment: It seems to me that the problem must be with the way you wrote the data to the CSV file.  That's the code you need to show us, I would think.

Comment: the paths from firebug are a starting point to get you in the right area.  You're launching general expressions that arn't hitting everything you need, and you're losing the relational data between them in the process.  Even if you get the expressions to the point that you get them all, there's a good chance data will be mixed up.

I'd suggest navigating to a single node they all have in common, and then using relative xpath expressions or navigator commands from that element to get to the nodes you need.

Comment: Hi tiastowka:  I think you are correct about finding a single poit of reference for the data and using relative paths to the data items.  Still have to try it.  The misaligned cells shows up before writing data to csv.  Using len(item) shows there are different item lengths and hopefully using a common reference point will keep the data together. Thanks, Yankee26

Answer (score 0):

building on my comment:

```
import requests
from lxml import etree

url="""http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=apartment"""
url+="""&insert geo params here"""

r = requests.get(url)
h = etree.HTMLParser()

tree = etree.fromstring(r.text,h)

xp_info_nodes = """//div[@class='info']"""

xp_id = """h3[@class='n']/text()"""
xp_name = """h3[@class='n']/a[@class='business-name']/text()"""
xp_adr = """div[@class='info-section info-primary']/p[@class='adr']/span[1]/text()"""
xp_link = """.//a[@class='track-visit-website']/@href"""


info_nodes = tree.xpath(xp_info_nodes)
all_data = []

for node in info_nodes:

    #mandatory_nodes
    data = [
            node.xpath(xp_id),
            node.xpath(xp_name),
            node.xpath(xp_adr),

        ]

    #insert some function to clean up data[0] here.  its returning weird strings.

    ldata = len(data)
    data = [d for d in data if d]
    if len(data) != ldata:
        continue

    #optional
    optional_data = [
        data.append(node.xpath(xp_link))
    ]

    optional_data = [o for o in optional_data]

    all_data.append(data + optional_data)

for row in all_data:
    """print a line of your csv"""
```